# Not found: Table sql-practice-361723:warehouse_orders.orders was not found in location US -- GOOGLE Analytics

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics

Of note. When I remove the from section and run it in a separate query the code works. I can Inner Join, Outer Join, Left Join or Right Join. However, when I add the code back to the case query it returns the error message not found in location US.

Thanks,
M

SECTION OF CODE IN QUESTION

```
FROM `sql-practice-361723.warehouse_orders.Warehouse` AS warehouse
LEFT JOIN    
`sql-practice-361723.warehouse_orders.Orders`As Orders    
ON
warehouse.warehouse_id = Orders.warehouse_id
```

--> FULL CODE

```
SELECT
Warehouse.warehouse_id,
CONCAT(Warehouse.state, ':' , Warehouse.warehouse_alias) AS warehouse_name,
COUNT(Orders.order_id) AS num_of_orders,
(SELECT
COUNT(*)
FROM warehouse_orders.orders As orders) AS total_orders,
CASE
WHEN COUNT(orders.orders_id/(SELECT COUNT (*) FROM warehouse_orders.orders AS Orders)) <= 0.2
then "Fullfilled 0%-20% of Orders"
WHEN COUNT(orders.orders_id/(SELECT COUNT (*) FROM warehouse_orders.orders AS Orders)) > 
0.2
and COUNT(orders.orders_id/(SELECT COUNT (*) FROM warehouse_orders.orders AS Orders)) <= 
0.6
then "Fullfilled 21%-60% of Orders"
ELSE "Fullfilled more than 60% of Orders"
END AS fullfillment_summary 
FROM `sql-practice-361723.warehouse_orders.Warehouse` AS warehouse
LEFT JOIN
`sql-practice-361723.warehouse_orders.Orders`As Orders
ON
warehouse.warehouse_id = Orders.warehouse_id
GROUP BY
Warehouse.warehouse_id,
warehouse_name
HAVING
COUNT(Orders.order_id > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through and adjusted the code slightly. I adjusted the aliases to reflect to full location parameters of the data table in the Case portion of the code.

Also there was an error in the HAVINVG Count code. the () were incorrectly placed.

No idea why the alias did nor work as planned but the work around was simple to put the direct location into the CASE code and it solved my issue.

Of note although I thought the problem was in the FROM LEFT Join section the problem appeared earlier in the code where the table was already to be populated.

Any additional comments greatly appreciated,
M

Comment: I don't know what the having clause looked like before, but it's still wrong. HAVING
COUNT(Orders.order_id > 0) should be HAVING COUNT(Orders.order_id) > 0

Answer (score 0):

The actual video for this section is wrong, I spent hours on this and errors in the previous video. And the video also cuts at a point where the final HAVING statement is shown incorrectly. Annoying, but I'm learning!

I got this to finally work, they key being to provide full table names for the from clauses. :

```
SELECT  
  Warehouse.warehouse_id,
  CONCAT(Warehouse.state, " : ", Warehouse.warehouse_alias) as warehouse_name,
  count(Orders.order_id) as number_of_orders,
  (
    SELECT count(*) FROM `<project_id>.warehouse.warehouse_orders` Orders
  ) as total_orders,
  CASE
    WHEN COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT count(*) from `<project_id>.warehouse.warehouse_orders`  Orders) <= 0.20
    THEN "Fulfilled 0-20% of Orders"
    WHEN COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT count(*) from `<project_id>.warehouse.warehouse_orders`  Orders) > 0.20
    AND  COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT count(*) from `<project_id>.warehouse.warehouse_orders`  Orders) <= 0.60
    THEN "Fulfilled 21%-60% of Orders"
    ELSE "Fulfilled more than 60% of orders"
    END AS fullfillment_summary

FROM `<project_id>.warehouse.warehouse` Warehouse
LEFT JOIN
  `<project_id>.warehouse.warehouse_orders` Orders ON Orders.warehouse_id = Warehouse.warehouse_id
GROUP BY
  Warehouse.warehouse_id,
  warehouse_name

HAVING
  COUNT(Orders.order_id) >0
```

Answer (score 0):

Right! So I too faced the same issue and yes the instructor inputs the HAVING clause incorrectly. Its should be `HAVING COUNT(Orders.order_id) > 0` and not `HAVING COUNT(Orders.order_id > 0)`

Also, the key is to make sure you're naming everything correctly. It is easy to get confused with Orders and orders which is where I was having issues too.

Basically, my table name and dataset name are all in lowercase. The instructor used 'Order' and 'Warehouse' for aliasing the respective tables. In instances where you have `warehouse_orders.Table_name_as_per_explorer_tab`, so in my case that would be `warehouse_orders.orders`.

In places where we use `Orders.order_id` use `Alias_name_given.order_id`

This is what worked for me.

```
SELECT
Warehouse.warehouse_id,
CONCAT(Warehouse.state, ": ", Warehouse.warehouse_alias) AS warehouse_name,
COUNT(Orders.order_id) AS number_of_orders,
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        warehouse_orders.orders AS Orders
)
AS total_orders,
CASE
    WHEN COUNT(Orders.order_id) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warehouse_orders.orders AS Orders) <= 0.20
      THEN "Fulfilled 0-20% of Orders"
    WHEN COUNT(Orders.order_id) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warehouse_orders.orders AS Orders) > 0.20
    AND COUNT(Orders.order_id) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warehouse_orders.orders AS Orders) <= 0.60
      THEN "Fulfilled 21-60% of Orders"
  ELSE "Fulfilled more than 60% of Orders"
  END AS fulfillment_summary
FROM
`<YOUR_PROJECT_NAME>.warehouse_orders.warehouse` AS Warehouse
LEFT JOIN
`<YOUR_PROJECT_NAME>.warehouse_orders.orders` AS Orders
ON Orders.warehouse_id = Warehouse.warehouse_id
GROUP BY
Warehouse.warehouse_id,
warehouse_name
HAVING
COUNT(Orders.order_id) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

it is like there an error in the following, the expression is not accepted
CONCAT(warehouse.state, ":" , warehouse.warehouse_alias)AS warehouse_name

Comment: Would you mind providing a suggested solution on top of the identified error?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).